# bash script to restart Apache automatically

Tags: apache, bash

I wrote a bash script to restart Apache when it hanged and send email to the admin. The code is shown below. the code will restart Apache if the number of Apache process is zero. The problem is: Apache some time hangs and processes is still not zero,so in this case the script will not restart Apache.
The needed is: how do I modify the code to restart Apache if it hanged and the processes is not zero.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `pgrep apache2 -c` -le "0" ]; then
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
pkill -u www-data  
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
 echo "restarting....."
SUBJECT="Apache auto restart"
# Email To ?
EMAIL="me@mydomain.com"
# Email text/message
EMAILMESSAGE="apache auto restart done"
# send an email using /bin/mail
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" "$EMAILMESSAGE"
fi
```

Comment: Fix the disease, not the symptoms. You should be asking how to determine why apache is hanging (probably in ServerFault) and then fix that... not how to restart it when it hangs.

Comment: Why did you reinvent the wheel here, the startup scripts found in /etc/rc.d or similar (depending on unix/linux installation) has the capability to do a restart, but then again, check your error logs as to why you have to restart the server, usually /etc/rc.d/3/rc.httpd restart or similar...

Comment: Hi. Juliano your are right. I am looking for the root cause of problem but I think this kind of scripts is a "must have" because it is possible in future it will hang and this script will temporary solve the problem.

Comment: hi, Tommieb75. I will not restart the server, I will only restart the service "Apache".

Comment: "Server" refers to Apache in this case, not the computer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

We used to have Apache segfaulting sometimes on a machine; here's the script we used trying to debug the problem while keeping Apache up. It ran from cron (as root) once every minute or so. It should be self-explanatory.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script that checks whether apache is still up, and if not:
# - e-mail the last bit of log files
# - kick some life back into it
# -- Thomas, 20050606

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
THEDIR=/tmp/apache-watchdog
EMAIL=yourself@example.com
mkdir -p $THEDIR

if ( wget --timeout=30 -q -P $THEDIR http://localhost/robots.txt )
then
    # we are up
    touch ~/.apache-was-up
else
    # down! but if it was down already, don't keep spamming
    if [[ -f ~/.apache-was-up ]]
    then
        # write a nice e-mail
        echo -n "apache crashed at " > $THEDIR/mail
        date >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Access log:" >> $THEDIR/mail
        tail -n 30 /var/log/apache2_access/current >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Error log:" >> $THEDIR/mail
        tail -n 30 /var/log/apache2_error/current >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        # kick apache
        echo "Now kicking apache..." >> $THEDIR/mail
        /etc/init.d/apache2 stop >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        killall -9 apache2 >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        /etc/init.d/apache2 start >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        # send the mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Good luck troubleshooting!" >> $THEDIR/mail
        mail -s "apache-watchdog: apache crashed" $EMAIL < $THEDIR/mail
        rm ~/.apache-was-up
    fi
fi

rm -rf $THEDIR
```

We never did figure out the problem...

Comment: That `rm -rf` makes me nervous. It looks like you're writing two files. Just explicitly delete them then `rmdir $THEDIR`.

Comment: Which one is better to test the apache server,  using wget or check the status of the apache using  /etc/init.d/httpd status? I am thinking using wget will put more stress to the server.

Comment: I would certainly recommend using an actual http request, because if Apache just hangs deadlocks or something (i.e. the process is still running), the init script won't tell you. And if your server cannot handle one request per minute, a crashing Apache is the least of your worries ;)

Comment: Thanks. But I think that will work for checking mysql server status?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson rmdir fails because the output from wget is in there. I used your suggestion and had the script running for a few weeks; I just discovered I had thousands of files building up in $THEDIR

Comment: @jessica You'd have to `rm $THEDIR/mail $THEDIR/robots.txt` before you do `rmdir $THEDIR`. Also consider passing `-O $THEDIR/robots.txt` instead of `-P $THEDIR` to just overwrite the output file if an earlier run of the script didn't clean up for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Can the count of a process really be less than zero?

This should be sufficient:

```
if ! pgrep apache2 -c >/dev/null; then
```

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant, however true it may be.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to send an http request to apache (e.g. using `wget --timeout=10`) and if that request times out or fails (exit status != 0), you kill and restart apache.

Comment: how would you do this one?

Answer (score 1):

Why would Apache hang?  Can you get to the cause?

There are a number of scripts and tools out there to 'daemonize' apps and watch over them. As you seem to be on Debian or Ubuntu, have a look at the packages `daemon` and `daemontools`. I am sure there are others too.